# Best free Twitter analytics tool?

Tags: social-networks, analytics, twitter

I need to collect some data from several twitter pages for a university project.

I searched the internet among the various tools available but they all are not free or they give few data relating to a short period.

The information I need are:

**Number of Followers**

**Number of Tweet per day**

**Engagement** (eg. as the average number of Retweet / Favorites for tweet compared to the number of followers)

For better understand what I'm looking for see [this tool](http://likealyzer.com) for Facebook pages, I would like to find something similar for Twitter pages. Is possible?

Do you know a valid Twitter Analytics tool with the simple informations I listed above?

Thanks to everyone who will try to help.